# How to display grouped records using select and optgroup in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create grouped dropdown select using Angular. In my case group is `make`.

```
const cars = [{
        make: "audi",
        model: "r8",
        year: "2012"
    },
    {
        make: "audi",
        model: "rs5",
        year: "2013"
    },
    {
        make: "ford",
        model: "mustang",
        year: "2012"
    },
    {
        make: "ford",
        model: "fusion",
        year: "2015"
    },
    {
        make: "kia",
        model: "optima",
        year: "2012"
    }
];
```

So the output would be dropdown select with options:

```
audi
- r8
- rs5
ford
- mustang
- fusion
kia
- optima
```

And I wondering whether should I transform this object before? For example similar to this solution: https://medium.com/@edisondevadoss/javascript-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key-afc85c35d07e

Or maybe there is another better way. I found this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-optgroup. But the structure of object is kinda different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah so you should transform the object before, similar to the medium article's answer (on make's basis).

Even in the stackblitz example you can see the main name is something on which it has to be grouped.

So your ngFor will show a group1 and then its opt-groups and then group2 and its children so on. So transforming is the way in my opinion as well.

**UPDATED**

So from your stackblitz example(the one you shared above) it will go something like this

[image]

```
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <optgroup *ngFor="let item of optGroups" label="{{item.name}}" >
       <option *ngFor="let sub of item.data" value="{{sub.value}}"> 
         {{sub.text}} 
       </option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

one ngFor on optgroup and another on option

And you can get the transformed response from this snippet

```
 let group = this.cars.reduce((r, a) => {
  console.log("a", a);
  console.log('r', r);
  r[a.make] = [...r[a.make] || [], a];
  return r;
 }, []);
```

You will get the desired transformed response, which will be Array of makes and each make will have number of items inside

Look at this image below, I have already tried it. Then you can use ngFor the way I have mentioned above

[image]

Comment: Can you give some example how you see this?

Comment: you mean the ngFor example or what?

Comment: How it can be transformed to be working with grouped ngFor.

Comment: Okay let me see. 
Do you have some stackblitz setup or something already which I can see?

Comment: Maybe you can modify that stackblitz that I sent in main post?

Comment: That HTML code won't work, since you iterate over the object's array. So you shouldn't call `item.name` i'll try to improve that code.

Comment: It is already working!. The first screenshot that I have sent I did it on stackblitz already. The example there with animals names and types on stackblitz its from that.  'name' is the category like 4-legged, flying-pets.Obviously you will do it according to your requirements in cars example. I already have given you the transformed part.  You will do it like in initial ngFor "item of group" and then for nested loop item.model, item.year etc.

Comment: To make it work I had to use keyvalue pipe.
`<select name="cars" id="cars">
    <optgroup *ngFor="let item of optGroups | keyvalue" label="{{item.key}}" >
       <option *ngFor="let sub of item.key" value="{{sub.value}}"> 
         {{sub.text}} 
       </option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>`

Comment: One more question, can you tell me how can I change sorting to desc? So it would be `[kia, ford, audi]`

Comment: yeah that works too, but it worked even without that. Anyways as long as your problem is resolved that matters :)

Comment: So there is a sort() method which sorts an array in ascending then you can call reverse() on that sorted array you will get descending order so `arr.sort().reverse`. Though the simplest way is in your ngFor on optGroup array call .slice().reverse() `optGroup.slice().reverse()`

Comment: Hm `.reverse()` not working and `.slice().reverse()` cleaning up the array

Comment: worked for me both of them. So then on your main array chain the methods `.sort().reverse()`.  If you have updated stackblitz, share it I will check.

Comment: Check this. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GG4PXCHZ4VUD
It's because my key is name. That's why reverse doesn't work. Dunno how to fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216565/discussion-between-wahab-shah-and-dipix).

Comment: Ok problem is because of reduce that sorting alphabetically.
I've created new post check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559508/how-to-force-reduce-to-not-sorting-alphabetically-in-javascript

Comment: sure I will check